# How can I sort my DataTables row by date?

Tags: php, jquery, sorting, datetime, datatables

I want to sort my column by date:

```js
var table = $('#table').DataTable({
   "order": [[0, "desc"]],
});
```

But here is my result:

```
29.06.17
27.06.17
26.06.17
22.08.17
18.10.17
15.09.17
```

What I would expect is this:

```
18.10.17
15.09.17
22.08.17    
29.06.17
27.06.17
26.06.17
```

June, then August, then September and then October....

I tested also:

```js
"columnDefs": [
   { "type": "date-dd.mm.yy", targets: 0 }
],
```

But this didn't change anything.

Comment: I guess you have to work with dateobjects to make it sortable. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: What language is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dataTables `date` type uses `Data.parse()` which only supports a limited set of date formats. European style dd.mm.yy is not parseable thus the dates is alpha sorted.

You can deal with [**data attributes**](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html), i.e adding a `data-sort="10/18/17"` to each column, but I think it is easier to create a small plugin that return valid dates :

```js
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "jarla-date-pre": function(a) {
     a = a.split('.');
     return new Date(a[1]+'/'+a[0]+'/'+a[2])
   }
});
```

Use it like this :

```js
columnDefs: [
  { type: 'jarla-date', targets: 0 }   
]
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vad94dcs/**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `render` function which allows you to both format the date for display and use the raw date value for sorting.

The following code uses the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) javascript library to format the date.

```
{
     data: 'DateField',
     render: function (data, type, row) {
     // If display or filter data is requested, format the date
     if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') {

                    return (moment(data).format("ddd DD/MM/YYYY (HH:mm)"));
                }
    // Otherwise the data type requested (`type`) is type detection or
    // sorting data, for which we want to use the raw date value, so just return
    // that, unaltered
                return data;
            }
        },
```

Link to source at the [datatables forum, here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25196/render-date-and-retain-order-functionality-ajax-object).