# How can I sort my jquery datatable by date?

Tags: jquery, date, sorting, datatables

This is the content of my datatable:

```
05.06.2020 10:46
14.08.2020 11:18
17.09.2020 01:24
17.09.2020 04:42
20.08.2020 01:47
20.08.2020 04:37
22.09.2020 02:05
23.09.2020 13:52
28.04.2020 02:46
28.04.2020 12:00
```

The sorting is not working correctly, as I am expecting the colums start with the newest date.
This is my approach:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "data":{{ data|raw }},
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
  ....

   'createdCell':  function init(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
       var unixTimestamp = moment(cellData, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM').unix();
        $(cell).html(cellData);
        $(cell).attr('data-order', unixTimestamp);
   }
```

But still the sorting is wrong.
I tried this solution [How can I sort my DataTables row by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808260/how-can-i-sort-my-datatables-row-by-date) but it did not work for me.

Comment: @billynoah it is a json object

Comment: As well as the excellent "orthogonal data" approach mentioned by billynoah, another flexible approach is to use `moment.js` - as presented in [this walkthrough](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18). There are a few questions and answers on SO relating to that approach.

Comment: For orthogonal data, it sounds as if you may need to reformat your input date into a sortable format. If so, see the render function in [this example](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data#Computed-values). So, the sortable format would be a string like this: `2020.09.22 02:05`, as an example. That will sort fine, as a regular string.

Comment: Why does data-order not work https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Comment: Data-order is working OK for me. I can provide an example if that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution that worked for me:

```
"order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
"columnDefs": [
  {
        "type": "date",
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
          var DateCreated = moment(data, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          return DateCreated;
        },
        "targets": 0
      },
  ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the timestamp into your object and use [Orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data). I could give you an example more specific to your case if you provide a snippet of the the object and more of your Datatables init params, but it's something like this:

```
var table_data = [
    {
        "date": {
            "display": "05.06.2020 10:46",
            "timestamp": "1303681234"
        }
    }
]

var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "data": table_data,
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "columns" : [{
        data: {"_" : "date.display", "sort" : "date.timestamp" },
    }]
});
```