# date sorting for USA doesn't work in javascript using moment function

Tags: javascript, sorting, momentjs

I use the following format to display the date:
`$.fn.dataTable.moment('M/DD/yy HH:mm A')`

and that's how I define the date column in my datatable:

`{"sType": "date", "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "120px" }`

When displaying the data, I'm using the follwoing logic:

`item.SettlementDate != null ? moment(item.SettlementDate).format('M/DD/yy HH:mm A') : ""`

That's how it's displayed on the screen:
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

---

This is what I have now after update:

```
"mRender": function (data, type, row, meta)
{ 
return moment(data, 'MM.DD.YYYY HH:mm').format('M/DD/YY HH:mm');
}
```

I need to display PM/AM format as well and that's why I added `A`
With `A` it doesn't sort but does sorting without `A`:

This is without `A`
[image]
[image]

And this is with `A`

```
"mRender": function (data, type, row, meta) {
 return moment(data, 'MM.DD.YYYY HH:mm A').format('M/DD/YY HH:mm A');
}
```

Onlydescending order looks like working
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort my jquery datatable by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104908/how-can-i-sort-my-jquery-datatable-by-date)

Comment: No, this did not work for me

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67639512/edit) to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is the original datatype of "data", and what is the ordering logic you're using?

Comment: I found the solution. I just had to remove `{ "sType": "date"}`